# Jquery: unable to add whitespace to the placeholder of contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

For my contetedible div, I need to use javascript to prepend some whitespace in the placeholder, in order to center the text of a flexible-length placeholder.

However, it seems impossbile to add multiple whitespace before the paceholder text.

Demo below:

```
<html>
box1
<div id="comment_box1" class="comment_box" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;somewords"></div>
box2
<div id="comment_box2" class="comment_box" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder=" "></div>

</html>


<style>
.comment_box[data-placeholder]:not(:focus):not([data-div-placeholder-content]):before {
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    color: #aaa;
}
.comment_box{
    min-height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  width: 550px;
  text-align: left;
}
</style>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("I need to use jquery to make box2 same as box1");
    var a=" ".repeat(3); // I tired var a="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp" not working also
    var b="somewords";
    $("#comment_box2").attr("data-placeholder",a+b);

});
</script>
```

Comment: why don't you add padding via CSS? or text-align to center

Comment: Why with Javascript?

Comment: text-align center also makes the user input aligned to center, I want user input aligned to left while placeholder is centered

Comment: _“text-align center also makes the user input aligned to center"_ – only if you _apply_ it to the user input. You are using a `:before` pseudo element for the placeholder – so make that `display:block`, and then center-align the text in it.

Comment: Should I delete the psudo element? or if possbile @CBroe could you write a bit code? Thanks.

Comment: I’m saying, add `display:block; text-align:center;` to the styles for your first CSS selector you have shown …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are dealing with non breaking spaces (5 of them), so you need to use the correct char:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("I need to use jquery to make box2 same as box1");
    var a= String.fromCharCode(160).repeat(5);
    var b="somewords";
    $("#comment_box2").attr("data-placeholder",a+b);

});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mt5zy5r8/

Though if alignment is your goal, css is a far better solution, as noted by @Cbroe in comments:

```
.comment_box[data-placeholder]:not(:focus):not([data-div-placeholder-content]):before {
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    color: #aaa;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mt5zy5r8/1/

Comment: That’ll make the approach chosen by OP work … but doesn’t change the fact that it is rather the wrong one to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe Absolutely, css is the way forward, but this answers the specific question, and i thought the problem was interesting enough to answer in that sense. I'll make an edit to highlight that

Comment: Not criticizing your answer wrong being wrong, `fromCharCode` (or maybe the `\u…` unicode notation) is the way to go if you want to create non-breaking space characters in JS. Only NBSPs are the “wrong” solution for the underlaying problem to begin with ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("I need to use jquery to make box2 same as box1");
    var a= $("#comment_box1").attr("data-placeholder"); // I tired var a="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp" not working also
    var b="somewords";
    $("#comment_box2").attr("data-placeholder",a);

});
```

It gets the attr value from comment_box1 stores it in a and places it in comment_box2

Comment: I make the box1 to clarify the effect I want to achieve. Thanks but your answer can't fix my problem though. The point of the question is to figure out how to add whitespace for contenteditable div placeholder using javascript.

Comment: _“The point of the question […]”_ – … is the wrong one to begin with. All it needs are two additional CSS styles for the pseudo element that you’re using to display the placeholder.

Answer (score -1):

You should use css to align the text in the placeholder, use the pseudo classes for input-placeholder.

Here is an example of the snippet, i add some classes to style text inside the input, and also the input itself when it has a placeholder text:

```css
.first-input {
  width: 100px;
}
.second-input {
  width: 300px;
}
.third-input {
  width: 500px;
  color: red;
}
input {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
input:placeholder-shown {
  border-color: red;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="first-input" placeholder="hello">
<input type="text" class="second-input" placeholder="hello">
<input type="text" class="third-input" placeholder="">
```